# Adding a delegate to the touch dispatcher seems to cause a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, cocos2d-iphone, crash

I'm using Cocos2d version 2.1 and I was wondering what the new new syntax is for

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

Everytime I compile my code, the simulator crashes with the message

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: it goes back to xcode to main.m file and shows the following #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
        return retVal;
    }
}        

Then it also shows this in the output box libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: That's the full text of the message?

Comment: so what should I do? because when I take out the Delegate part it warns me that it can't find the function.

Comment: add an exception breakpoint (google it)